# scss compilation issue in angular lib created using angular-cli

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli, angular-library

Created(`ng build my-lib`) an angular lib with global scss then bundled into one file and copied to lib's folder.

```
dist-lib/my-lib/lib/sass/my-lib.scss
```

Now **my-lib.scss** imports some resources like

```
@font-face {
    font-family:"Roboto Regular";
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
    src: url("../resources/fonts/roboto-regular/Roboto-Regular.eot?") format("eot"),  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
         url("../resources/fonts/roboto-regular/Roboto-Regular.woff") format("woff"), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
         url("../resources/fonts/roboto-regular/Roboto-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");  /* Safari, Android, iOS */
}
```

I copied the resources folder to my lib at location

```
dist-lib/my-lib/lib/resources
                             /fonts
                                   / roboto-regular/Roboto-Regular.eot
```

Now in my Application's **styles.scss** file I am importing **my-lib.scss** file like this

```
@import "../dist-lib/my-lib/lib/sass/my-lib";
```

But this is showing error

```
ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.scss)
Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: D:\SK\Study\Angular\AngularLib\MyLib\dist-lib\my-lib\lib\sass\my-lib.scss:10:9: 
Can't resolve '../resources/fonts/roboto-regular/Roboto-Regular.woff' in 'D:\SK\Study\Angular\AngularLib\MyLib\src'

   8 |     font-style:normal;
   9 |     src: url("../resources/fonts/roboto-regular/Roboto-Regular.eot?") format("eot"),  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
> 10 |          url("../resources/fonts/roboto-regular/Roboto-Regular.woff") format("woff"), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
     |         ^
  11 |          url("../resources/fonts/roboto-regular/Roboto-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
```

I guess the resources are getting resolved relative to file **src/styles.scss** instead of relative to **dist-lib/my-lib/lib/sass/my-lib.scss**

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I am building/serving my project through Angular-Cli, so the plugins/loaders that it uses to deal scss was not resolving the issues of relative (to the library itself) URLs (`url(../)`).

To solve this I created **fonts.css** not **fonts.scss** that I ship with the library. And end user has to import this **fonts.css** as well.

And this is working now, though this does not sound a good solution, I got this workaround till the time.

**Update : Providing font.scss**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    src: url('../assets/fonts/proxima-nova-light/ProximaNova-Light.eot');
    src: url('../assets/fonts/proxima-nova-light/ProximaNova-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../assets/fonts/proxima-nova-light/ProximaNova-Light.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../assets/fonts/proxima-nova-light/ProximaNova-Light.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../assets/fonts/proxima-nova-light/ProximaNova-Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../assets/fonts/proxima-nova-light/ProximaNova-Light.svg#ProximaNova-Light') format('svg');
    font-weight: 300;
  }

  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    src: url('../assets/fonts/proxima-nova-regular/ProximaNova-Regular.eot');
    src: url('../assets/fonts/proxima-nova-regular/ProximaNova-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../assets/fonts/proxima-nova-regular/ProximaNova-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../assets/fonts/proxima-nova-regular/ProximaNova-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../assets/fonts/proxima-nova-regular/ProximaNova-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../assets/fonts/proxima-nova-regular/ProximaNova-Regular.svg#ProximaNova-Regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: 400;
  }

  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    src: url('../assets/fonts/proxima-nova-medium/ProximaNova-Medium.eot');
    src: url('../assets/fonts/proxima-nova-medium/ProximaNova-Medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../assets/fonts/proxima-nova-medium/ProximaNova-Medium.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../assets/fonts/proxima-nova-medium/ProximaNova-Medium.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../assets/fonts/proxima-nova-medium/ProximaNova-Medium.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../assets/fonts/proxima-nova-medium/ProximaNova-Medium.svg#ProximaNova-Medium') format('svg');
        font-weight: 500;
  }

  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    src: url('../assets/fonts/proxima-nova-bold/ProximaNova-Bold.eot');
    src: url('../assets/fonts/proxima-nova-bold/ProximaNova-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../assets/fonts/proxima-nova-bold/ProximaNova-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../assets/fonts/proxima-nova-bold/ProximaNova-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../assets/fonts/proxima-nova-bold/ProximaNova-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../assets/fonts/proxima-nova-bold/ProximaNova-Bold.svg#ProximaNova-Bold') format('svg');
    font-weight: 700;
  }
```

As I have used font.scss that will be compiled to font.css file as the lib build process using this script

```
"build-lib-fonts": "node-sass --include-path scss ./projects/project/src/lib/styles/_fonts.scss ./dist-lib/project/styles/fonts.css",
```

Comment: Can you please share the content of your font.css file? I am hitting the same problem, but I don't understand how to fix. Thanks